# Spring call controller after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom authentication filter and provider which checks for an `Authentication` header and then verifies it against my database. Now I want to call the controller after the authentication instead of redirecting as this is a REST API. How do I call the controller with the current request. All I get at the moment is a white page with HttpStatus 200.

```
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("apiAuthenticationFilter")
        public TokenAuthenticationFilter apiAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler,
                TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) throws Exception {
            TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
            filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
            return filter;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/internal**").hasAuthority("READ_ALL")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(apiAuthenticationFilter(null, null), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(this.appProvider)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
                .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have fixed my problem. The problem was in the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that my `TokenAuthenticationFilter` extended. The `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` does not call the filter chain after being successful authenticated.

The following changes will make it possible to use an `Authentication` Header without redirecting:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    // ... attempAuthentication method and other stuff

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response); //THIS is very important as the original method 
                                           //does not execute this very important method 
                                           //cause the default is to use a redirect.
    }
}
```